# Сколько [модем]ов нам нужно?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Предлагаю объединить метки [модем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc) и [модемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b). Главной сделать [модемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b).

Обе метки не имеют описания. У одной метки *16* вопросов, у другой *8*.

Comment: Хочется добавить в заголовке «...чтобы закрутить лампочку».

Comment: @alexolut добавьте? )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Объединил [modem](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/modem) и [модем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc) в [модемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b). Если позже возникнут сомнения, правильно ли выбрана основная метка, синоним всегда можно «развернуть» в другую сторону.

Comment: А что, "ымедом", звучит интригующе :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский [meta-tag:отунрёвзар-сутатс]!